# Use a template image in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm looking for a way in Shiny to allow a user to change the values for (a) and (d) and update the rest of the confusion matrix. The key is that I'd like the text and numbers to appear in this visual format. Is there any way to use a template image and overlay objects that get updated dynamically? A better approach?

We have [this so far](https://globalhealthresearch.shinyapps.io/confusion-matrix/), but the layout is not ideal.

[image]

Comment: What I would do is working on the css, adding custom classes or even id to shiny elements. It should be fairly easy to get what you want, depending on you level of proficiency with css.

Comment: Thanks, @GGamba. I can see how that would be a superior solution. I don't know much CSS, but I understand what I need to explore.